# PRNG to Obtain Random Subset (PORS) Success Probability

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

**PORS** (**PRNG to ORS**) is a secure variant of the **HORS** few-time signature scheme. In **PORS**, instead of using a hash function, it uses a message (and salt) as a seed of PRNG and query it until obtains **k** distinct indices.

As stated in 6.2 [Security of PORS](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/909.pdf)

**How does a non-adaptive adversary performing a brute-force attack against PORS has at most the following success probability for each message ??**
$$ = \frac{kr!}{(kr-k)!}\frac{(t-k)!}{t!}$$

**Please help me to understand it.**

Answer (score 1):

Per the beginning of section 6.1 of the paper, this value is equal to
$$\frac{kr}t\frac{kr-1}{t-1}\cdots\frac{k-r-k-1}{t-k-1}$$
and as they go on to say:

> This corresponds to the probability that $k$ distinct values uniformly distributed in a set of size $t$ all fall into a subset of size $kr$

To see this, note that the probability that for the first value there are $t$ possiblities of which $kr$ lie in the subset; if the first does lie in the subset, then there are $t-1$ remaining possibilities of which $kr-1$ lie in the subset and so on.

Cryptanalytically, the attacker is assumed to have seen $k$ signed messages each of which reveal $r$ of the $t$ secret values (we assume the worst case that the $r$ are distinct). The attacker can forge if they can generate a message (which hashes to a uniform random subset of $k$ values) for which all $k$ values are ones that they have already seen. The probability for this is as described.